# UUID default value on PSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, sqlalchemy

I'm creating my database tables inside a flask application via SQLAlchemy.
According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20532531/how-to-set-a-column-default-to-a-postgresql-function-using-sqlalchemy), my code should look like this:

```
id = db.Column(db.CHAR(36), primary_key=True, server_default=str("uuid_generate_v4()"))
```

which, after migrations and upgrades are done, its definition on the database looks like this:

```
 id character(36) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL DEFAULT 'uuid_generate_v4()'::bpchar,
```

Is this the correct way of specifying a UUID default value in PSQL?

Comment: Your datatype should be `UUID`, not `CHAR(36)`. Have a look at the [uuid-ossp extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/uuid-ossp.html). That's assuming SQLAlchemy support the UUID datatype of course.

Comment: Also I'm not sure about the `str(..)`. I think it should be `server_default=sqlalchemy.text("uuid_generate_v4()")` or just `server_default="uuid_generate_v4()"`

Comment: yea, I agree with @ypercubeᵀᴹ. I think there is a problem with that.

Comment: Yes, the `server_default=sqlalchemy.text(...)` is needed. Otherwise sqlalchemy thinks you want to have a string constant as the default.